# How to create a FadeTo() animation based on BindableProperty change, MVVM style?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

Let's say I have a view, with an `<Image>` element in it, that is visible based on whether it has a non-null property or not in the viewmodel. Like this:

```
<Image IsVisible="{Binding HasPhoto}" Source="{Binding Url}" />
```

With this ViewModel (only copied the relevant part):

```
private string url {get;set;}
public string Url {
    get => url;
    set {
        url = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HasPhoto));
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public bool HasPhoto { get => Url != null; }
```

And somewhere in the ViewModel, I set: `Url = null`. This will cause HasPhoto to become false, and immediately render the `<Image>` element invisible, leaving no room to animate with `.FadeTo(0)` in the behavior. This is my current behavior implementation:

```
public class FadingBehavior : Behavior<VisualElement>
{
    public uint FadeTime { get; set; } = 250;

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(VisualElement bindable)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        bindable.PropertyChanged += VisibilityMightHaveChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(VisualElement bindable)
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
        bindable.PropertyChanged -= VisibilityMightHaveChanged;
    }

    private void VisibilityMightHaveChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var element = sender as VisualElement;
        if (args.PropertyName == VisualElement.IsVisibleProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            var fadeToValue = element.IsVisible ? 1 : 0;

            element.Opacity = -fadeToValue + 1;
            element.FadeTo(fadeToValue, FadeTime);
        }
    }
}
```

This is fine, when the the `<Image>` becomes visible, because first it becomes visible, then it fades from 0 opacity to 1. But, for fading out this is not good, as the Url is removed instantly, rendering the image empty and invisible, so the fade-out animation cannot even start.

What is a good way to create an animation based on a bindable property value change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are not far from a good solution.

What I would do is to inherit from `Image` and create `FadableImage` with bindable property called something like `VisibilityHelper`. Then when you assign the value to it the Image will still be visible and you can initiate the animation in a way that you already do. Just in the end when animation completes you should check the value of `VisibilityHelper` and if it is still the same also set `IsVisible` to the appropriate value.

Comment: I was hoping there is an easier way to do it, just I don't know about it. But yes, that's the way I had to go in the end. Thank you :)